# computation of a pixel coordinates of a photographed monitor

Tags: python, opencv, pyautogui

Does anyone know how one might go about calculating the x,y coordinates of, say, a button or an image on a monitor by analysis of a picture of that monitor?

My laptop's webcam faces the work computer's monitors, so that a photograph through the webcam will capture the database entry as well as the phone system. I need to compute the coordinates of the elements on those monitors from the picture of the monitors so that I can send the coordinates to a microprocessor, which in turn would programmatically control keyboard and mouse.

Anyone know how to do this in python?

Comment: How are you capturing the image of the monitor?

Comment: opencv, from a webcam

Comment: The resolution and screen size, etc are known, so is there some way to determine how many inches in from monitor's edge an element is and then calculate how many pixels that distance would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of problem is called "object detection", and is frequently solved by training an ML model to draw a bounding box around the objects you're interested in. That training usually involves feeding the model examples images where you have drawn the bounding boxes manually and some negative examples where the monitor and/or the button are not present.

In your case, you would want to detect the monitor and then detect the button you're looking for. By subtracting the coordinates of the monitor from the button, you would get a very approximate x,y location of the button on the screen.

That said, this approach is likely to be very brittle and error prone. If it were possible to get the video output being sent to the monitor directly (using a splitter perhaps), that would give you much better data to work with.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. That is quite unfortunate. I was hoping I could just detect the edges of the monitor and do some simple conversion by identifying how many inches those edges are and then converting inches to pixels since I know the resolution of the screens. There's no module that can simply find an instance of an element in a photo in relation to the overall photo the way pyautogui can relate the coordinates of an element on the screen by analyzing a screenshot that I could just add some math to?

Comment: Probably not. The image that you're going to get from the web cam is going to be imperfect in a few ways that will cause problems. It will be slightly skewed, scaled or offset depending on the position. The colors will be slightly different based on the lighting. Are you absolutely sure you need the x, y coordinates? Many times there are keyboard keys/commands that can sidestep the need to send mouse input.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. Maybe I can get around the problem altogether. Say, by figuring out what the coordinate are one time, because the position of everything remains the same. Only thing that changes is the phone number. The work computer connects to a virtual machine, and then through a separate VPN to the database. All keyboard shortcuts are disabled and access to any external storage etc is denied. Only thing it will accept is keyboard and mouse (otherwise I would have tried to run my software from a portable python interpreter on a flash drive).

Comment: I suppose I could use pytesseract to get the number, pass that to the microcontroller, and then trial and error x,y coordinates for the mouse. Hate to make any automation software that blind though :(

Comment: There are options to capture the video going to monitor, like this: https://www.amazon.com/Geekworm-Raspberry-Supports-1080p25fps-Compatible/dp/B0899L6ZXZ?th=1

Comment: Wow, that's awesome. But, still, I don't know of a module that can replicate what "pyautogui.LocateCenterOnScreen("img.png") with a screenshot

Comment: If you were working with a clean capture from the video source, you could use the OpenCV function for "template matching", which finds a smaller "template" image inside of a larger image. Docs are here: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

Comment: And then numpy to calculate x,y axis of the object from the result of minmaxloc? Thanks a lot, man. Been a big help